# Sci-fi book with a human colony planet that brings the dead back to life

Tags: story-identification, reincarnation

An alien planet.  Humanity is colonizing.  Just a single wrinkle.  Anyone who touches down on the planet soon develops a "shadow".  A loved one who's died on Earth simply comes back to life and starts following the colonist.

The story is similar to the movie Solaris in this respect.

At the very beginning of the story, the female protagonist is landing on the planet for the first time.  She discovers instead her shuttle went down in the mountains and she died!  She's a "shadow" (I may not be using the author's lexicon to describe the one that's been reincarnated by the planet).

The author is a female and it was a debut novel if my memory serves me right.  I found the book in the new Sci-fi section of the local library in the last couple of years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ghost Planet** by Sharon Lynn Fisher. Elizabeth Cole, a psychologist travels to a newly settled world, Ardagh 1, where every colonist is partnered with a dead loved one.

> As the story progresses, She finds out her shuttled crashed and she died and is tethered with her supervisor, who created the protocol of refusing to interact with these "partners", however, physical separation causes pain to these ghosts. She and her supervisor are attracted to her and try to ignore the protocol.

[image]

Comment: Keith, thanks for the edit, I'm trying to figure out the "spoiler" block

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!